# Use MS Virtual Smartcards as keystore on server

Tags: windows, smartcard, pkcs#11

I'm currently trying to find a possibility to store priv. keys on a server in a secure way on hardware. Basically it is a requirement, that keys on a critical server are to be stored on secure hardware. The "classical" approach for this is to use a HSM, but since very few servers in different projects need to be secured that way, alwas buying a HSM is too expensive.

So my idea was to use windows virtual smartcards to store the server keys and the software running on the server should use PKCS#11 to talk to this smartcard.

Is it possible to use virtual smartcards to store priv. keys for server applications and is there a possibility to use virtual smartcards without the necessity to enter the pin all the time? Afaik there is a possibility to encrypt a server with bitlocker but get the "key" at startup from the AD, maybe something the like is possible with virtual smartcards.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure there is PKCS#11 library available for MS Virtual Smartcard but I've been using [SoftHSM](https://github.com/disig/SoftHSM2-for-Windows) for the same purpose with a great success.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Is is possible to bind SoftHSM to the TPM of a server?

Comment: @pinas AFAIK it is not. SoftHSM is software-only implementation of cryptographic key store accessible via PKCS#11 API.